# Diffrence of two same values is not zero

Tags: python, precision, floating-accuracy

When I compare two numbers at python, even though they are exactly the same, the difference between these two numbers is not zero, but something really small (<10^(-16)).

e.g.

```
if A == B:
    print('We are the same')
```

Nothing happens.
But:

```
if A - B < 10^(-16):
    print(A-B)
```

It prints the difference.

Where is the problem?

Comment: this question is not a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What are the exact values of `A` and `B`? Please show a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Reopened

Comment: @Gsk yes you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

in Python, the `^` operator execute an **exclusive or**, so `10^(-16)` means `10 XOR (-16)`, which correctly returns `-6` (which is lower than `A-B`).
If you wanted to execute an exponentiation, you have to write `10**(-16)`, and your check is now working as expected.

This means that your code should be:

```
if A - B < 10**(-16):
    print(A-B)

# OUTPUT: 0
```